# Handle keypress/keydown/keyup on kendo-contextmenu in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-contextmenu

I have a kendo-grid contained inside a chromium browser. The grid has a couple of context menu items appearing on a right click on any of the cell of the grid. Irrespective of the cell right clicked, the context menu items are same.

What I am unable to do is to capture either a keypress/keydown/keyup event when the kendo-popup having context menu items is open. End goal is to do key based navigation and event handling on the context-menu items.

Thanks in advance.

Kendo package version: 2021.2.511,
Kendo grid version: 5.1.2,
Angular version: 12.0.0

Comment: I think a stackblitz would be useful here